# sqlite field value rounded off at the time of storing in a double field

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have stored location in my sqlite database.

```
CREATE TABLE city
    (
        latitude NUMERIC,
        longitude NUMERIC
    )
```

Below are the value :-

```
latitude = 41.0776605;//value in db - NUMERIC stored as DB - also tried with TEXT
longitude = -74.170086;//value in db - NUMERIC stored as DB - also tried with TEXT
```

**UPDATE - When I execute the below query i inspect the value and get that it is giving me the same value which is stored inside the DB but when I am trying to store it in a double variable it is somehow rounding it value and that is why i am getting incorrect value in a variable. Any solution for this?**

```
final String query = "SELECT * FROM city";    
cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (null != cursor) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Latitude == " + cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude")));
                Log.i(TAG, "Longitude == " + cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude")));
            }
        }
```

Result :- At the time of storing it to String or double variable the values are changes and it is giving me below value.

```
Latitude = 40.4127
Longitude = -74.25252
```

I don't want round off this values. Is there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you storing the values as text or numbers?

Comment: Show the table schema (`"CREATE TABLE...."`) and also the code you're using to add the values to the database.

Comment: Store your lat/long as TEXT in the DB. retrieve and insert as if they're doubles.. done.

Comment: @dymmeh the type of the database column doesn't really make any difference. SQLite uses dynamic typing depending on the data being inserted. See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @GrahamBorland, I added the create query.. And i have filled the database earlier and not having any query for insertion of record. I am only retrieving values from the table.

Comment: How do you store in the database? This is not a rounding problem it seems - the difference is just too big

Comment: @GrahamBorland - I understand the dynamic typing of sqlite. My issue is that there is some intermediate step when retrieving specific types of data which is causing loss of precision. This is possibly a bug with android's implementation of sqlite or possibly with sqlite itself. The storage mechanism is obviously working correct if he can view the DB values and they are there without any data loss.

Comment: I am storing the whole thing in the database like this way....."id","CityName","State",41.0776605,-74.170086..but as the problem is with location I am asking about that thing only here and represented question accordingly...

Comment: Also when I run query from the SQLite Query Browser it works fine but at the time of getting it through programming I don't know what goes wrong..

Comment: Ok..Got some thing which like to add...at the time of retrieving its not giving any error but when i store it inside the double variable somehow its truncating or rounding of the value which i get from the database. Now I am getting correct value from the database..

Answer (score 2):

SQLites writes and reads floating-point values as a 64-bit value that is in the same format as Java's `double`.
There is never any any rounding going on.

Your problem is with the conversion of the values to strings.
Use a helper like [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) or [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to specify the number of digits you want.

Comment: Yes you are right I debugged the code and came to know that i am getting correct value from the DB but at the time of storing it inside a double variable it is somehow rounding it. So for that i need to use formatter or decimalformat? Or any other solution for this?